# floating sidebar needs to be 100% height issue

Tags: html, css

I am looking for a solution to have an sidebar thats the same height as the content part. I have tried a lot of stuff but nothing is working. As you can see in the fiddle the sidebar is not a 100% as his parent(and the content part).

example here http://jsfiddle.net/94mGd/

CSS

```
  html{
      min-height:100%;  
  }
  body{
      min-height:100%;
      background-color:#eee;
  }
  #container{
      background-color:#ccc;
  } 
  aside{
      width:260px;
      float:left;
      background-color:#333;
      min-height:100%
  }
  #content{
      min-height:100%;
      margin-left:300px;
  }
  .dummy-height{
      height:2000px;
      background-color:#777;
  }
```

HTML

```
  <div id="container">     
      <aside> 
      sidebar  
      </aside>

      <div id="content">
          <div class="dummy-height">
          dummy
          </div>
      </div> 
  </div>
```

Comment: Do you need 2000px height for the .dummy-height{
    height:2000px;
    background-color:#777;
}

Comment: Given that you've got a non-fluid layout there, have you considered setting a background image on #container to give the desired appearance? It wouldn't actually make the aside element that high, but could get you the same visual result.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Need CSS sidebar height to expand with content](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1610710/need-css-sidebar-height-to-expand-with-content)

Comment: Re my background image suggestion: http://jsfiddle.net/technotarek/gKtQ6/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just give absolute positioning to the element and it will work:

http://jsfiddle.net/94mGd/3/

```
  aside{
      position:absolute;
      width:260px;
      float:left;
      background-color:#333;
      min-height:100%
  }
```

Similar Question page(solved) : [How to make a floated div 100% height of its parent?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3049783/how-to-make-a-floated-div-100-height-of-its-parent)

To solve the problem of 100% height together with float use a parent div for float:

```
<div id="floatL" style="float:left;">
  <aside> 
  sb   
  </aside>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/94mGd/5/

Comment: This negates `float: left;` you might as well remove it.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add height: 100% to every parent element You have not added this to #container.

```
#container {
      background-color:#ccc;
      height: 100%;
}
```